# How to make an integer validation function that does not accept floating point values?

Tags: c++, validation, integer

`getRegionTotal()` is the function I'm using for validation right now. It works pretty well in that if the user enters something like "twenty" or -7, it will not accept that and it will keep asking for new values until it gets one that is valid. However if the user enters 60.7 for the number of accidents in the north region, it will accept 60 and drop the .7 part. Then it will give both the regular instructions and the more specific instructions when it asks for the number of accidents in the south region.

```
//These will hold the number of accidents in each region last year
int northTotal = 0;
int southTotal = 0;
int eastTotal = 0;
int westTotal = 0;
int centralTotal = 0;

//passing 0 for northTotal, southTotal etc. because main doesn't know
//values of them until the function returns a value. When it returns a value
//it will go into the variables on the left. getRegionTotal will get the number
//of accidents for a region from the user and prompt the user using the string that
//is in the first argument.
northTotal = getRegionTotal("North", northTotal);
southTotal = getRegionTotal("South", southTotal);
eastTotal = getRegionTotal("East", eastTotal);
westTotal = getRegionTotal("West", westTotal);
centralTotal = getRegionTotal("Central", centralTotal);


int getRegionTotal(string regionName, int regionTotal)
{
    //instructs user to enter number of accidents reported in a particular region
    cout << "\nNumber of automobile accidents reported in " << regionName << " " << cityName << ": ";
    //while regionTotal is not an integer or regionTotal is negative
    while (!(cin >> regionTotal) || (regionTotal < 0) )
    {
        //give user more specific instructions
        cout << "\nPlease enter a positive whole number for the number of\n";
        cout << "automobile accidents in " << regionName << " " << cityName << ": ";
        cin.clear(); //clear out cin object
        cin.ignore(100, '\n'); //ignore whatever is in the cin object
                                //up to 100 characters or until
                                // a new line character
    }
    //returns a valid value for the number of accidents for the region
    return regionTotal;
}
```

Comment: Why not parse the float and drop the decimal places using casting to int, or alternatively check if the parsed number had decimal places (e.g. using modulo operator)?

Comment: The decimal places are dropped automatically. I'm not sure how I would check that with the modulus operator. If I change the while loop condition to `while (!(cin >> regionTotal) || (regionTotal < 0) || (regionTotal % 1 != 0) )` the problem remains

Comment: You need to _parse_ a float not an int - later you convert it (but it was only an idea - it is a bit dirty ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the whole line and make sure you've consumed the whole line.

With iostreams:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    int result;

    if (!(iss >> result >> std::ws && iss.get() == EOF))
    {
        // error, die. For example:

        std::cout << "Unparsable input: '" << line << "'\n";
        continue;
    }

    // else use "result"
}
```

With stdlib:

```
#include <errno>
#include <cstdlib>

char const * input = line.c_str();   // from above, say
char * e;
errno = 0;

long int result = std::strtol(input, &e, 10);

if (e == input || *e != '\0' || errno != 0)
{
    // error
}
```

The two approaches are fundamentally identical, but the former may be more "idiomatic C++". That said, if you already have an existing string, the `strtol`-approach is a neat alternative, since it gives you precise error handling: did you consume the whole string (if not, `e` points to the next character); did you consume *any* of the string (if not, `e` points to the beginning); was there an overflow or underflow (check `errno`). On the other hand, the iostreams approach lets you consume trailing whitespace (thanks to `>> std::ws`), which the `strtol`-solution doesn't.

There's also `std::stol` which wraps `strtol` (and similarly for `strtoull`/`strtod` etc.), but it throws an exception on error, and I believe that exceptions are not the right tool for structuring control flow of *normal* behaviour like reading user input. Also, you cannot control how those wrappers operates; for example, the succeed even if they don't consume the entire string (but don't tell you how far they got), and you cannot specify the number base.

Comment: One last check is necessary in the second version: that the string wasn't empty to begin with.

Comment: How could it?  If the string was empty, the only thing `*e` could point to is `'\0'`.  (One would expect some sort of error in `errno` if the string was empty, but the standard says otherwise.)

Comment: And there's a typo in your correction.  You don't want the `*` in `*e == input`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Ah, of course. I got that confused. I think the `*e` is right, though.

Comment: The second is right.  The first no.  (`*e` has type `char`, and you're comparing it to a `char const*`.)